# Not able to bind dynamic value in rating control

Tags: windows

I am using Bratched.Tools.Rating control for rating, but not able to draw rating using JSON / API data. I have used double and string both type of value but its empty, while we input hard coded value then its working fine not sure what the issue, can any one suggest. (Rating Control is non-editable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer late but i was confronted to the same problem and this is the only post who expose the problem, si i will give the anwser :

```
<rating:RatingControl ItemsCount="5"
                          Value="{Binding ValueRank, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          IsEditable="True">
```

Mode = twoway and specify the updatesourcetrigger to propertychanged and it will works.